# Authentication with using abstract classes asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

please any help or tutorial about developping an authentication with using many user , i have a class named USER and then i have 3 abstract classes Administrator,Secretary,Responsable , i want to develop an authentication method with using abstract classes , any help or tutorial pleaase .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may help you.

http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m7-security&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building

And you can get more resources about asp.net mvc security here.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security